# How to get all rows of a table that share a value on a specific field?

Tags: mysql, sql

For Example

If i have a table named students that has 4 fields id,fname,lname and dob (date of birth) How can I retrieve all students' names that share birthdays (without asking for a specific date of Birth) as well as the date they are sharing?

**id** int primary key not null and auto_increment
**fname** and **lname** are varchar
**dob** is date

```
id    fname     lname       dob

1.    Nick      Tailor      1993-04-27
2.    Mary      White       1987-11-13
3.    Helen     Wilde       1993-04-27
4.    George    Bishop      1981-02-29
5.    John      Walker      1981-02-29
6.    Vincent   Valentine   1981-02-29
```

and the result being

```
fname     lname       dob

Nick      Tailor      1993-04-27
Helen     Wilde       1993-04-27
George    Bishop      1981-02-29
John      Walker      1981-02-29
Vincent   Valentine   1981-02-29
```

Mary isn't shown anywhere since she doesn't share dob with anyone in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this helps

```
SELECT fname, lname, dob
FROM students
WHERE dob IN (SELECT dob FROM students GROUP BY dob HAVING count(*) > 1);
```

Make sure to check your database config for the dob column, when running the query on my end to test if it works, I got a date error because there was no february 29 in 1981 :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists`:

```
select e.*
from exampledata ed
where exists (select 1
              from exampledata ed2
              where ed2.dob = ed.dob and ed2.id <> ed.id
             );
```

You can check if there are duplicates by simply doing:

```
select ed.dob, count(*), group_concat(ed.id)
from exampledata ed
group by ed.dob
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Thank u for the reply. When i modified the names to use it on my DB it returns empty set and i do have 2 people that share the same date of birth.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
SELECT s1.* FROM `students`s1
INNER JOIN `students` s2 on  s1.`dob` = s2.`dob` and s1.`id`<> s2.`id`
GROUP BY s1.`id`
```

Answer (score 1):

This works on Oracle, and I believe it will work on MySQL too:

```
select *
  from xtb
 where xfl in (select xfl 
                 from xtb
                group by xfl
               having count(*) > 1)
 order by xfl
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using year to extract those duplicate data, here I've used a sample:

```
SELECT Temp.fname, Temp.lname, Temp.dob
FROM (
   SELECT m.fname, m.lname, m.dob, 
   COUNT(YEAR(dob)) AS CNT FROM TableName m 
   GROUP BY m.fname, m.lname, m.dob
) AS Temp ---- Sub query
WHERE Temp.CNT > 1 ---- Here check if there is any year greater than 1
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution Query :**

```
SELECT fname as 'First Name', lname as 'Last Name',dob as 'Birthday' FROM students WHERE dob IN(SELECT dob FROM students GROUP BY dob HAVING COUNT(id) > 1) ORDER BY dob;
```